# Firefox mouse click misbehavior under nightwatch/selenium testing

Tags: javascript, firefox, selenium, selenium-webdriver, nightwatch.js

I am testing a web page using nightwatch/selenium. The web page is a collection of procedures that are organized into folders, similar to what you'd see in Windows Explorer. Folders can be expanded/collapsed by clicking on them and the procedures can be clicked on to display/hide buttons that operate on each procedure.

My test logic clicks (browser.click()) on a folder to expand it then clicks on an underlying procedure to display its buttons. A click invokes a bit of javascript to toggle membership to a DOM class for the selected folder or procedure, which CSS translates into the item being visible or not. The nightwatch custom command test logic looks like this:

```
module.exports.command = function(folder,procedure)
{
    var folderCSS = '.folder .col-title[data-title="' + folder + '"]'
    var folderOpenCSS = '.folder.open .col-title[data-title="' + folder + '"]'

    // Ensure the desire folder is visible, click on it to expand,
    // and ensure that it has expanded
    this.waitForElementVisible(folderCSS,1000)
    this.click(folderCSS)
    this.waitForElementPresent(folderOpenCSS,3000)

    // Insert extra click on something else here to make the procedure click work, e.g.
    //var folder2CSS = '.folder .col-title[data-title="folder2"]'
    //this.click(folder2CSS)

    // Wait for the desired procedure title to be visible and click on it,
    // exposing the run button
    var procedureCSS = '.procedure[data-procedurename="' + 
                       folder + '/' + procedure + '"]'
    var procedureTitleCSS = procedureCSS + ' .col-title'
    this.waitForElementVisible(procedureTitleCSS,5000)
    this.click(procedureTitleCSS)

    // Wait for the run button to be visible and click on it to start
    // the procedure
    var procedureRunCSS = procedureCSS + ' .run-icon[data-original-title="run"]'
    this.waitForElementVisible(procedureRunCSS,1000)

}
```

This all works fine under nightwatch/selenium against both the phantomjs headless browser and Chrome, but doesn't work using Firefox. A click on the folder (this.click(folderCSS)) works as expected, but clicking on the procedure (this.click(procedureTitleCSS)) doesn't toggle the button display state. The final waitForElementVisible in the code above times out no matter how long the wait; however, if I uncomment the snippet of code between the folder and procedure clicks in the code above, that extra folder click lets the procedure click through and toggles the procedure button display state. I've tried a this.pause() in place of that extra click and it doesn't work, so it seems the procedure click event is getting blocked.

Is there something inherently wrong with the way I'm testing for click results or the way the click is being issued, or is there some known problem with Firefox under nightwatch/selenium?
I'm running with Windows 8.1, Firefox 43.0.4, node v4.2.2, selenium 2.48.2. Incidentally, this used to work with Firefox 43.0.

UPDATE: Tried running with the --verbose command line option for debugging selenium interaction and the clicks work properly, so I can't use that to help analyze the problem.